# Multiplication tab php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a multiplication table using PHP but in my code the number 1 is skipped i don't know why.
Can you please guys help me to solve this problem.
Thanks a lot.

```
<?php
$codeHTML = '<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Programmation pour le Web</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>';
$codeHTML .= '<body><h1> Table de multiplication </h1>
<table border = "2" width = "100">';
// Creation de la table
for($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){
  $codeHTML .= '<tr>';
  for($j = 1; $j < 6; $j++){
    $p = $i*$j;
    $codeHTML .= "<td> $p </td>";
  }
  $codeHTML .= '</tr>';
}
$codeHTML .= '</table>
</body>
</html>';
echo $codeHTML;
?>
```

And i want an output to be like :

```
x  1  2  3  4  5
1  1  2  3  4  5
2  2  4  6  8  10
3  3  6  9  12 15
4  4  8  12 16 20
5  5  10 15 20 25
```

Comment: What means "number 1 is skipped" ? What do you want to achieve, could you provide expected output?

Comment: in my table the multiplication start only with the number 2 even tho the number 1 is on the top left of the table

Comment: [Works as expected for me](https://onlinephp.io/c/00405).  When you view your page source in the browser, what exact output do you see and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: So you want to have `1 2 4 8 10` in first row ?

Comment: i want to have in the firt line the number 1 till 6 and in the first colonne 1 till 6 and the multiplications in middle of the table

Comment: Just edit your question with full example of your desired output, all rows and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you provide **expected outpus** is much easier to help you, here is **what you want**:

```
<?php
$codeHTML = '<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Programmation pour le Web</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>';

$codeHTML .= '<body><h1> Table de multiplication </h1>
<table border = "2" width = "100">';

$codeHTML .= "<tr> <td>x</td>";
for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
  $codeHTML .= "<td>$i</td>";
}
$codeHTML .= '</tr>';

for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++){
  $codeHTML .= '<tr>';
  $codeHTML .= "<td>$i</td>";
  for($j = 1; $j <= 6; $j++){
    $p = $i*$j;
    $codeHTML .= "<td> $p </td>";
  }
  $codeHTML .= '</tr>';
}
$codeHTML .= '</table>
</body>
</html>';
echo $codeHTML;
?>
```

**Output is:**

```
x   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   1   2   3   4   5   6
2   2   4   6   8   10  12
3   3   6   9   12  15  18
4   4   8   12  16  20  24
5   5   10  15  20  25  30
6   6   12  18  24  30  36
```

Comment: i want to something like that : x 1 2 3 4 5 6 in the first row / column

Comment: @Mehdi You can achieve this without using another foreach loop. Check my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75075929/2437590

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you want ?

```
<?php
$codeHTML    = '<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Programmation pour le Web</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>';
$codeHTML    .= '<body><h1> Table de multiplication </h1>
<table border = "2" width = "100">';

for ( $i = 0; $i < 6; $i ++ ) {
    $codeHTML .= '<tr>';
    for ( $j = 0; $j < 6; $j ++ ) {
        $p = $i * $j;
        if ( 0 == $i && 0 == $j ) {
            $p = 'x';
        } elseif ( $j == 0 ) {
            $p = $i;
        } elseif ( $i == 0 ) {
            $p = $j;
        }
        $codeHTML .= "<td> $p </td>";
    }
    $codeHTML .= '</tr>';
}

$codeHTML .= '</table>
</body></html>';

echo $codeHTML;
```

This will output:

[image]